# ActiveRecord validation fails at seeding with Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am creating a new instance of a working application, and try to seed the User model. One custom validation fails at seeding , but works fine in normal operation:

The User model is linked to the Group model through a HABTM relation. A user must at least belong to the group Everyone, of which id is 0.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

# Validations
  validate :member_of_Everyone_group

# Relations
  has_many :groups_users
  has_many :groups, through: :groups_users

private 

  def member_of_Everyone_group
    errors.add(:base, :EveryoneMembershipMissing) unless self.group_ids.include? 0
  end

end
```

**group.rb**

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord

# Relations
  has_many :groups_users
  has_many :users, through: :groups_users

end
```

**groups_user.rb**

```
class GroupsUser < ApplicationRecord

### Validations
  validates :is_principal, uniqueness: { scope: [:group_id, :user_id] }
  validates :group_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }

  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :groups

end
```

At seeding, the following error is raised:

> rails aborted! NameError: uninitialized constant User::Groups
>
> app/models/user.rb:174:in `member_of_Everyone_group'

- In normal operation, this validation acts correctly.
- In rails console, I can check that the statement `group_ids.include? 0` works fine too

Can you help me to understand what's going wrong ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello! Can you also provide code from the `seeds.rb` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`belongs_to` should use the singular version of the model name, not the plural. In your `GroupsUser` model, change those lines to:

```rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :group
```

Answer (score 0):

A user `has_many` groups, but in `groups_user.rb` there is a uniqueness validation for `group_id` in the scope of user. This seems to be a contradiction.

Comment: Actually, a user can belong only once to a group, so the pair user_id,,group_id has to be unique.

Comment: Then you don't actually need a many-to-many relationship between users and groups. You could change it into a `has_one / belongs_to` relationship. Simplicity brings peace of mind.